# Using a text editor as pastebin / pasteboard (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, text, editor

There is a feature I've used a lot in a Windows program, a text editor called NoteTab (there is a similar implementation via plugin in Notepad++). In NoteTab there is an option to use the current document as pasteboard. It is a very useful option when you are copying bits of text or code from different sources, because they get neatly pasted in that text document.

I was wondering if some Mac text editor has a similar feature. I know it is possible to use a pastebin utility, like Jumpcut, but I really find the simpler, straight approach in the NoteTab feature preferable.

Thanks in advance!